# Show $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{ y_n-x_n} = f'(x_0)$ using Taylor

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:[a, b]\to R$ differentiable at $a<x_0<b$. Using taylor series show that if $x_n \to x_0^-$ and $y_n \to x_0^+$ then

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{ y_n-x_n} = f'(x_0)$$

After I wrote the taylor expansion of 1's order I just returned to the definition of the derivative so that didn't help much...
Any other suggesions? Thanks

Comment: $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$, $f(y_n)-f(x_n)=(y_n-x_n)f'(c)$ where $c$ between $x_n$ and $y_n$.

Comment: @metacompactness how? MVT? but those are sequences

Comment: @metacompactness your argument needs $f'(c)\to f'(x_0)$, which isn't given.

Comment: @user251257 As $x_n\to x_0$ and $y_n\to x_0$, $c\to x_0$.

Comment: The taylor expansion of order 1 including the remainder estimation is just the definition of differentiable. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @metacompactness I know. But, how do you show $f'(c)\to f'(x_0)$ as $f'$ is not necessarily continuous at $x_0$?

Comment: @user3697301 Use the fact, that $(f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x)h) / h \to 0$ for $h\to 0$, $h\ne 0$.

Comment: Is $f$ twice differentiable or continuously differentiable - or really just differentiable?

Comment: @user251257 to include the reminder you need that f is twice differentiable

Comment: @Adam: Nope. That's just the definition of differentiable. It is *not* uniformly in $x$!

Comment: so there isn't a solution ?

Comment: @user251257 I dont understand what you mean. The reminder is an integral which depends on the second derivative of $f$. Or what reminder do you mean?

Comment: @Adam: I don't need an explicit formula for the reminder. I only need the estimation. The one I need is already implied by the definition of differentiable.

Comment: Why does everyone keep saying reminder? It's the remainder!

Comment: Also, @Adam, the remainder comes for free with the definition of differentiation. The nice forms of the remainder come with higher smoothness. What we know without that is $$f'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ and so $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f'(x)(x-x_0) - f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=0.$$ The function $R(x)=f'(x)(x-x_0) - f(x) - f(x_0)$ is the remainder. It satisfies $R(x)/(x-x_0) \to 0$ as $x\to x_0$. The integral form and other forms you see associated with Taylor expansions are upper bounds on the function $R(x)$ as $x\to x_0$.

Comment: Correction to my above comment: the equations should read: $$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ and $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x_0)(x-x_0)-(f(x)-f(x_0))}{x-x_0} = 0$$ making $$R(x) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0)-(f(x)-f(x_0))$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to mention that we are not using Taylor series to solve this problem. We are using Taylor expansions, and in particular we are using the first order Taylor expansion. A differentiable function is not guaranteed to have a Taylor series with positive radius of convergence, but it can be approximated by Taylor polynomials.

The first order Taylor expansion is given by $$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + R(x)$$ where $\frac{R(x)}{x-x_0} \to 0$ as $x \to x_0$.

Now we examine $$\frac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} = \frac{f'(x_0)(y_n-x_0)-f'(x_0)(x_n-x_0) + R(y_n) - R(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}$$ $$=f'(x_0) + \frac{R(y_n) - R(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}$$

Thus in order to demonstrate the claim, we must show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{R(y_n) - R(x_n)}{y_n-x_n} =0.$$

We need to convert this into an expression resembling $R(x)/(x-x_0)$, to claim that it goes to zero. This is where $y_n > x_0$ and $x_n < x_0$ comes in.

Notice that $$\left| \frac{R(y_n) -R(x_n)}{y_n-x_n} \right| \le \left|\frac{R(y_n)}{y_n-x_n} \right| + \left| \frac{R(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} \right|$$ and replacing $y_n - x_n$ with $y_n-x_0$ and $x_n - x_0$ only increases the fractions thus:

$$\left| \frac{R(y_n) -R(x_n)}{y_n-x_n} \right| \le \left| \frac{R(y_n)}{y_n-x_0} \right| + \left| \frac{R(x_n)}{x_n-x_0} \right| \to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$.

This last step is the crux of the matter, and it also appears in the answer provided by @user251257.

Comment: Very good answer and thanks for mentioning "the crux of the matter". Easier versions of the problem deal with sequences $x_{n}, y_{n}$ tending to $x_{0}$ and $x_{n} \neq y_{n}$ and added assumption of continuity of $f'$. The above solution shows that just existence of derivative $f'$ is sufficient provided we also ensure that $x_{n} < x_{0} < y_{n}$. +1

Answer (score 4):

For $n\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$ 
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} - f'(x_0) \right|
&= \left| \frac{f(y_n) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(y_n - x_0) - (f(x_n) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x_n - x_0))}{y_n - x_n} \right| \\
&\le \left| \frac{f(y_n) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(y_n - x_0)}{y_n - x_0} \right| + \left| \frac{(f(x_n) - f(x_0) - f'(x_0)(x_n - x_0)) }{x_n - x_0} \right| \\
&\to 0 + 0.
\end{align}
$$